Reduce Space From /dev/centos/root
In my system using xfs file system with the below mentioned drive structure, I want to reduce space from /dev/centos/root volume in volume group Centos. Since xfs cannot be directly reduced, my method would be to move all data from /root and then recreate the logical volume with less space then recopy all the data back.
For the first test I am just trying to copy data from root to /dev/sda4, then only format /root with mkfs.xfs and re-copy data back to see if there is no issue booting the system. However when I boot after this procedure i get error "Superblock has uknown read-only compatible features 0xe enabled".
What can i do to resolve this issue.
Partition   Filesystem  Mount Point Size        Used        Unused      Flags
/dev/sda1   xfs                     1.00GiB     171.64 MiB  852.36 MiB  boot
/dev/sda2   lvm2 pv     centos      9.00 GiB    9.00 GiB    0.00 B      lvm
/dev/sda3   lvm2 pv     centos      10.00 GiB   10.00 GiB   0.00 B      lvm
/dev/sda4   xfs                     17.99 GiB   6.59 GiB    0.00 B      lvm


What version of xfsprogs did you use for mkfs, and what version of the Linux kernel are you booting?

Linux 3.10.0-1160.83.1.el7.x86_64 & xfs_db version is 6.6.0 which I used from Gparted live CD console
